# In C# how could I sort a jagged and 2d rectangular array based on 2nd column in ascending order, based on values not just alphabetical order?

Tags: c#

I have a jagged or a simple 2d rectangular array (doesn't matter which one is sortable in anyway, I know how to convert between them back and forth). The array is in string format, since the first column is text, but the second column contains double values only. How could I sort the array in an ascending order based on their values not the alphabetical order?
The values would be for example these numbers: 10.0368; 27.2023; 15.21; 4.886

```
public static void Sort<T>(T[][] data, int col)
    {
        Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        Array.Sort<T[]>(data, (x, y) => comparer.Compare(x[col], y[col]));
        Array.Reverse(data);
    }
```

I used this extension method until now, but as it seems to me, it only sorts in alphabetical order. => 10.0368; 15.21; 27.2023; 4.886 (1; 1; 2; 4)
How I would like it to work would be obviously this: 4.886; 10.0368; 15.21; 27.2023.

I tried to find an answer on Google, and in some of the books I have about C#, but I only found the answer for arrays that would have only numbers in it.

If you need any more in depth details to solve the problem, I will provide you with the info you need.

Comment: In fact `Comparer<string>.Default` is equivalent to `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`. It compares according to the lexicographic convention of the current culture and is sensitive to casing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used this extension method until now, but as it seems to me, it only sorts in alphabetical order.

This is true, because you said earlier that your array is in `string` format. Hence, your

```
Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
```

gives you a string comparator, which compares based on lexicographic order.

If you know that the second element of the array contains a `double`, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
public static void Sort<T>(T[][] data, int col) {
    var comparer = Comparer<double>.Default;
    Array.Sort<T[]>(
        data
    ,   (x, y) => comparer.Compare(
            double.Parse(y[col].ToString())
        ,   double.Parse(x[col].ToString())
        )
    );
}
```

`x[col].ToString()` does nothing because `x[col]` is already a `string`, but it lets you keep your code generic, instead of rewriting as non-generic `string[][]` method.

Note that you do not have to reverse the result if you reverse parameters that you pass to the comparator.

Comment: Instead of negating (unary `-`) the result of `Compare(,)`, it is better to swap its two arguments. In the unlikely case the result is `res = int.MinValue`, that is a fixpoint for negation, so `-res` is equal to `res` in that case.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for the comment, swapping parameters is indeed better.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight For this row (Comparer <T> comparer = Comparer <double>.Default;) I get an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections. Generic.Comparer <double> to System.Collections.Generic.Comparer <T> ". And also the double.Parse sections have a problem with conversion.

Comment: @DanielBlack Please try edited code, I used `var` instead of copied code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you for the answers now it works like a charm.